# SP13: Saving PDF to Document Library

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library, content-type

My objective is to have a way to save a pdf directly back SharePoint to designated document library. I have multiple pdf documents too.  When using a WORD document a way to make sure it's saved to the correct SharePoint document library is to pin the document library through "recent" (depending on the version of Word you are using).  The problem is that pdf does not give the option to pin.

To solve this problem do you think I create a content type with the pdf files attached would be the best solution?  If so, how would I add more than one document as a content type?

Or is there a workflow  that I can create that will allow the pdf to be saved directly to SharePoint document library without having to upload using "add document" option?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not quite sure what your question is. What are you using the 'Save' the PDF. Acrobat Pro, some other PDF editor or is this a code only solution?

Comment: @Muhimbi Sorry about that. The file opens in Adobe file and select 'Save' from the tool bar.